# How can I trigger the Jquery .on() function when the mouse button is pressed, instead of when it is released.

Tags: jquery

The Jquery code 
`$(element).on("click", selector, handler)`
, will trigger the handler function after the mouse button is released from the selected element. Is there a way to trigger the event when the mouse button is pressed?

Comment: try with `.on("mousedown", ...)`

Comment: please try, https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109754/difference-between-mousedown-and-click-in-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `.mousedown()` Function to achieve what you want:

```
$( "#target" ).mousedown(function(){});
```

Or you can use the `.on()` function and pass '*mousedown'* as the action:

```
$( "#target" ).on('mousedown', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mousedown()`

```
$(document).off("mousedown","#ID").on("mousedown","#ID", function(){
...
});
```