# How to filter by event type in Chrome DevTools Profile tab e.g. to see mouse clicks?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was trying to debug how long it takes for a new page to render when coming from another page of the website.

So what I did was:

- click start recording
- move mouse over to a link to go no another page
- click the link
- move mouse over back to the DevTools to stop recording

and then I want to see how long it takes between clicking and the new page loading on the profile.

The problem is that I have to move the mouse to the link of interest, and so I get several other events, e.g. mousemove and mouseover before clicking, making it hard to spot where the click event itself is. It is especially problematic because the click event might be quite short compared to the mousemove.

Is there a way to filter only the mouse click event?

Tested on Chromium 91, Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl + F on the Profile tab**

After not finding it on the web, I just tried Ctrl + F and that worked. It opens a search bar at the bottom, then I then type the name of the event of interest, e.g. `mousedown` and it highlights the single matching event with a red border:

[image]

For the specific case of clicking, note that there is also sometimes a `mouseclick` event, although it might not happen if the button is released on a different element. So what you usually want is just to look at `mousedown`: [Difference between mousedown and click in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109754/difference-between-mousedown-and-click-in-jquery)

Tested on Chromium 91, Ubuntu 20.10.