# JQuery Mouse Events

Tags: jquery, events

So my question is about how jQuery mouse events are handled.  Correct me if I'm wrong but the following events happen in this order:

```
.mouseDown
.click
.mouseUp
```

My question is does `.click` wait for `.mouseDown` to finish running before its called by default?  If not, is there something like `.promise` for animations that forces `.click` to wait?

Edit #1
Lots of these responses are touching on my question a bit, but what i would like to know is if `.click` will wait for the `.mouseDown` to completely run through before the code for `.click` starts running?  As in, its guaranteed to do so, or if i have to write logic to ensure that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572644/differentiate-click-vs-mousedown-mouseup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with jQuery, it's how the events are defined in javaScript.

A `click` event is a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup` *on the same element*.

In other words, the `mousedown` event fires first when the mouse button is pressed, then the `mouseup` event fires when the button is released, and if they both fired on the same element, the `click` event fires.

You can easily test this -> http://jsfiddle.net/4EUPm/

**EDIT:**

> Edit #1 Lots of these responses are touching on my question a bit, but
>   what i would like to know is if .click will wait for the .mouseDown to
>   completely run through before the code for .click starts running? As
>   in, its guaranteed to do so, or if i have to write logic to ensure
>   that.

Javascript has only one thread, so two functions **can not** execute at the same time, with a few exceptions, like asynchronous methods.

Also, a `click` waits for both the `mousedown` and `mouseup`, and then checks both of those to see that the target was the same element, so yes, a `click` event handler can not fire until after the `mousedown` *and* the `mouseup` event has fired, it's just not possible.

Wether or not every piece of code inside the `mousedown` event handler finishes before the `click` event handler is fired, is impossible to answer without knowing exactly what's inside those event handlers, but generally ***all*** the code in the `mousedown` event handler will finish before the code in the `click` event handler starts, unless there's async behaviour or other strangeness going on.

Comment: Thanks!  And if I sounded snide in my edit that wasn't the intention!

Answer (score 0):

The order is down,up,click. if you need to execute a delayed command in mousedown and would like to fire a second command if also the click event is fired, you can do something like this:

```
var clicked = 0;
$('#test').on('mousedown',function() {
//do animation stuff onmouse down
if(clicked)
{
    //do animation stuff onclick
    clicked = 0;
}
});

$('#test').on('click',function() {
 clicked = 1;
});
```

Comment: up is triggered when the mouse is released,(_obviously it means that the mouse has been pressed_) but click is triggered when the mouse is pressed and released

Comment: hey, is this kind of revenge ?

Comment: well probably yours is a revenge since you are misleading OP with wrong answer, and my answer has nothing wrong in it, or you haven't pointed out one yet.

Comment: once i downvoted yours, my answer got downvoted so i thought, any way thanks

Comment: i changed it, sorry by the way, didn't thought that alert would have side effects. Deleted my post and undoed the downvote.