# Image MoueUp event vs Button Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have seen that many users have asked how to make a clickable image in WPF.

Image has Mouseup event. It works like Button click event as I understand.

Is there any difference in Image Mouseup event and Button click event?

Comment: It helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572644/differentiate-click-vs-mousedown-mouseup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouseup event, user can click somewhere else on the screen and hold down the click button and move the pointer to Mouseup element, and then release the mouse.

Click event requires both the mousedown and mouseup event to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The MouseUp can happen in a different control from MouseDown. 
A Button can also be bound to a Command and thus separating your logic from the UI.