# Is there any method to replace initEvent in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to trigger the MouseEvent manually in typescript and it shows the initEvent is deprecated.

```
var clickEvent =document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
clickEvent.initEvent('mouseup',true,true);
```

[image: in this screenshot, it shows the initEvent is deprecated.]

Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) is now depreciated as shown in the hint. A note in the docs says:

> Note: Do not use this method anymore as it is deprecated. Instead use specific event constructors, like Event().

[`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) is an interface and it is **used** by different types of events. One of them being `mouseup`.
The new way of doing this is :

```
const mouseupEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup",{bubbles : true, cancelable: true});

// Dispatch the event.
document.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: There is a multi-select dropdown. I want to click the first value. Should I use "mousedown" instead of "mouseup"? like this
 ```const mouseupEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown",{bubbles : true, cancelable: true});
```

Comment: Mousedown works. There are subtle differences though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572644/differentiate-click-vs-mousedown-mouseup#:~:text=onMouseDown%20will%20trigger%20even%20when,released%20on%20the%20same%20object.

Comment: Do mark the answer as accepted/upvoted if it helps you.